# Which module loader for Aurelia2?

Tags: webpack, aurelia, aurelia2

I am starting a new typescript project with Aurelia2.
It gives me choice between Webpack and Dumber.
I don't know what to choose between those two.
My requirements for module loaders is:

1. Easy to debug in Chrome (I want to debug typescript files in chrome without struggle) - This is the MOST important
2. Easy to use (I don't want to mess around config files too much. I want to npm install external modules and use it)
3. I want to be able to use external files like images, css , less, external javascript libraries (not installed through npm) without much struggle

Performance is not an issue for me.
Please help me choose.
Thanks

**Update**
For the point 2. Easy to use...
I am currently using Aurelia 1 with Require bundler from the CLI. I've also, briefly used Aurelia 1 with Webpack at the beginning but the experience with it was bad for the 1st point -debugging typescript in browser and debugging generated javascript is a pain.
So the problem with Require and Webpack I have is third party libraries like ie. Devexpress, jsTree, libraries that don't use modules... Those libraries don't simply work and I need to change Aurelia configuration files (aurelia.json) to make them work. And finding the exact configuration is a pain for me (trial and error). For webpack, as I remember, I need to change webpack-config.json and know how webpack works for it to find modules.

For the point 3 easily use external files...
I use bootstrap themes for my project 90% of time. Themes I buy from WrapBootstrap. Integrating these themes is not easy for me. I don't know how to reference theme files like javascript files used in theme. In Aurelia word i like to use npm to install my libraries, it is very good and easy to do it, but if I get theme javascript files, I can't install them by npm (I don't mean the third party libraries like select2 the theme uses, only the javascript files the theme developer wrote), I cannot simply import them because they are not modules and are not know to Aurelia.

I am not a front-end developer, and I am not close to javascript system. This is why I like to use Typescript. But finding a solution to those problems takes time, time I don't have. I like Aurelia very much and wouldn't change it for any framework around now days.

What I like about Require is that I can do anything with it. Yes it needs configuration but at the and all works.
What I like about Webpack is HMR (hot-module-reload).

Comment: Being more specific regarding points 2 and 3 would make it easier to provide a proper answer. Do you have any frame of reference of what you're currently using and are happy/unhappy with? For example, an aurelia1 setup, or a setup with another SPA framework? Do you have any prior experience with webpack?

Comment: You can try both anyway :-) It's going be a small app as au2 is not production release yet. Both 1,2 is fine for any popular bundlers. And every bundlers has different way to deal with 3.

Comment: @huocp has a point - probably best to just try them out.

Comment: I would opt to go for webpack. Looking at your req's you may need some tweaks to get it working, and webpack will provide you maximum flexibility to do whatever you want. Dumber is ..... wel as the name says, easiest to setup, but less flexibility. Have to admit i'm more familiar with webpack

Comment: Thanks for Your suggestion  @Sander Spilleman, can You elaborate why, what is the strength of webpack over require.js in Duber?